# HTTPS request with TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA chiper and TLSv1

Tags: ssl, python-requests, tls1.0

I'm trying to make a request to a host with TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA chiper and TLSv1. When I try to do it with Python requests I get "OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')". Code example:

```
import requests

requests.get("https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/consultaCP/bofpostal.aspx")
```

I try to use the solutions describe in the next websites, but the problem continues:
https://gist.github.com/paxswill/5ed7273059b34e90b184
https://lukasa.co.uk/2017/02/Configuring_TLS_With_Requests/